# How to create a 'New Email with Attachment' option in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

With OS X Lion, the 'New Email with Attachment' option is missing from Finder. It is supposed to be replaced with the new "Share Button". Unfortunately, the only two ways I can share a file are Airdrop and iMessage. I use Mac Mail and this isn't present.

I checked 'Services' under 'System Preferences' and didn't see any option to add email to the share menu.

How do I customize the share to items?

Comment: Thats weird... Does your email account appear under "Mail, Contacts & Calendars" in System Preferences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the service present and *enabled* in the Services section of Keyboard Preferences?

You should see this:
[image: Services preferences]

If it's not there for some reason, you can recreate it easily in Automator.

Create a new Service in Automator, add the "New Mail Message" action to the workflow, and change the first drop down at the top so it reads "Service receives selected **files and folders** in any application". It should look like this:

[image: automator workflow]

Then save it, and you should have it available in your services menu.

Answer (score 1):

To create attachments, you can drag files from Finder into an empty email message. But I agree that this is too much work.

To save some keystrokes, you can create attachments by dragging files from **Finder** directly to the **Mail** icon in the dock - doesn't matter if **Mail** is running or not.

NB. In most cases dragging files to an app icon in the dock will do something meaningful, depending on the file type and the app.