# Create 'New Email with Attachment (via web-based Gmail)' option in Finder?

Tags: finder, email, gmail

I use the web version of Gmail (www.gmail.com; as opposed to a offline email client). I frequently send files as attachments.

I would like to be able to right-click on a file on Finder and, with one additional click, I would have a new blank e-mail message on Gmail (on a new window of my web browser; currently Chrome), with the selected file already added as an attachment.

This post shows how to to something similar. But the new messages opens up in Apple's Mail client.
[How to create a 'New Email with Attachment' option in Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62075/how-to-create-a-new-email-with-attachment-option-in-finder?rq=1)

Any ideas if what I want to do is possible?

Answer (score 3):

Try [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-6.html), the command line email client that you can use with shell scripting:

This page seems like a excellent resource:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mutt

New email from command line:

```
mutt -s "Subject" somejoeorjane@someserver.com -a somefile < /tmp/sometext.txt
```

Now you just need to modify that to go to Drafts instead of send (I have not tried this). Anyway, you can make an Automator service that runs one of these shell commands at mutt, then make a keyboard shortcut for that service.